# How to "Transpile away" log statements

Tags: typescript, debugging, logging, compile-time

I have my typescript project which has a bunch of code which only creates debug information. After profiling my application it turns out, that those have significant performance impact.

My current approach is setting a global variable `let debug=true`, and

```js
function log(statement: string):void {
  if(debug) console.log(statement);
}

// somewhere in the application
...
log(`hi mom! ${Factory.createDebugStatement()}`);
...
```

And this `Factory.createDebugStatement()` is computationally heavy.
Further, I want to avoid to clutter my application with `if(debug) log(...)`. I want typescript to remove the entire log statement.

Basically, I'm looking for a (convenient) `TS` 'equivalent' of the the idea in the following `C` structure:

```c
// header file
#ifdef ENABLE_DEBUG
#define DEBUG(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define DEBUG(...)                                                             \
  {}
#endif

//application

main(){
...
DEBUG("hi mom!");
...
}
```

Then, I can use `cc -DENABLE_DEBUG=1 main.c` to have those debug messages, if I omit the `-DENABLE_DEBUG`, the entire code is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit: Thanks to [Simon Lax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7655232/simon-laux) for pointing me to focus on the bundler parts...

I am using [rollup.js](https://rollupjs.org/), with the [plugin-strip](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/strip) plugin.
Then, with one switch in my `rollup.config.js` I can enable/disable the 'transpile away'

```
// src/main.ts
import fs from "fs";
class Service {
  expensive(res = ""): string {
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) res += i;
    return res;
  }
  normal(): string {
    return "Hi mom!";
  }
}

class Logger {
  public static log<T>(statement: T): T | undefined {
    console.log(statement);
    return statement;
  }
}

const s = new Service();

Logger.log(`${s.expensive()}`);

console.log(s.normal());

// and I can even use it in different situations, which usually expect the output.
fs.writeFileSync(
  "/tmp/abc",
  Logger.log(
    "not printed to screen nor to file but I wont have runtime exceptions, because TS hints me to catch the undefined case with the null'ish concealing",
  ) ?? "",
);
```

```js
// rollup.config.js
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import strip from "@rollup/plugin-strip";

export default [
  {
    external: ["fs"],
    input: ["src/main.ts"],
    output: {
      dir: "dist",
      format: "es",
    },
    strictDeprecations: true,
    plugins: [
      strip({
        include: ["**/*.ts"],
        functions: process.env.DEBUG ? [] : ["logger.log"],
      }),
      typescript(),
    ],
  },
];
```

```json
// package.json
 
 "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "bundle": "rollup --config rollup.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-strip": "^3.0.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^11.0.0",
    "rollup": "^3.15.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
```

then after running `npm run bundle` it will create the stripped version

```js
// dist/main.js
import fs from 'fs';

class Service {
    expensive(res = "") {
        for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            res += i;
        return res;
    }
    normal() {
        return "Hi mom!";
    }
}
const s = new Service();
console.log(s.normal());
// and I can even use it in different situations, which usually expect the output.
fs.writeFileSync("/tmp/abc", "");
```

and running `DEBUG=1 npm run bundle` it will create the full version

```js
// dist/main.js
import fs from 'fs';

class Service {
    expensive(res = "") {
        for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            res += i;
        return res;
    }
    normal() {
        return "Hi mom!";
    }
}
class Logger {
    static log(statement) {
        console.log(statement);
        return statement;
    }
}
const s = new Service();
Logger.log(`${s.expensive()}`);
console.log(s.normal());
// and I can even use it in different situations, which usually expect the output.
fs.writeFileSync("/tmp/abc", Logger.log("not printed to screen nor to file but I wont have runtime exceptions, because TS hints me to catch the undefined case with the null'ish concealing") ?? "");
```

(for completeness, my `tsconfig.json`)

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "transpileOnly": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For that I'd normally use a bundler that has "Tree-shaking", for example https://esbuild.github.io/api/#tree-shaking or https://parceljs.org/features/scope-hoisting/

In esbuild it's relatively easy: https://esbuild.github.io/api/#define

You define the `debug` variable* and the bundler automatically removes code branches that are never executed.

*Though you should use another name like `DEBUG_YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME` that is less likely to clash with code from your dependencies)

Comment: yes, I am using `rollup` already, and it emits `function log(statement){}` (shakes away the actual logging) However, it still emits `log(\`hi mom! ${Factory.createDebugStatement()}\`);`, hence the expensive statement is still executed.

Comment: Sometimes bundles can not detect if the function which output you are logging has side effects that are wanted, so the bundlers will not remove the expensive statement in such cases. maybe pass the expensive function as callback to a special log function, so that the log function calls it lazily: ``log(()=>`hi mom! ${Factory.createDebugStatement()}`)``

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble with Rollup to shake those statements off, **alternatively** you can prevent the `Factory.createDebugStatement()` from being invoked by passing `Factory.createDebugStatement` as a reference.

e.g.

```
Factory.createDebugStatement = (arg1, arg2) => {
  return `${arg1}-${arg2}`;
};

function log(statement: string, ...args: any[]): void {
  if (debug) {
    console.log(statement.replace('%s', args.map((arg) => (typeof arg === 'function' ? arg() : arg)).join('')));
  }
}

// somewhere in the application
log('hi %s mom!', Factory.createDebugStatement.bind(null, 'hello', 'world'));
// Output: hi hello-world mom!
```

Of course if your `Factory.createDebugStatement` don't take any argument, then you can simply do...

```
log('hi %s mom!', Factory.createDebugStatement);
```

The above won't invoke `Factory.createDebugStatement` if `debug=false`.
And this complies with 'Build Once Deploy Many' strategy.